# WCF: How to add a custom service?

Tags: wcf

I have a WCF service which contains 3 services.
It works in ConsoleHost, Windows Service and in IIS.

ConsoleHost runs them like this:

```
serviceHostCross = new ServiceHost(typeof(CrossService));
serviceHostRest = new WebServiceHost(typeof(DataRESTService));
serviceTransferHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(TransferService));
```

I'd like to add my own TCP service to the WCF service as a 4th.
It is not a WCF service.

How to add it using the same way?
E.g. somehow like this

```
serviceTcpHost = new ServiceHost (???) (typeof(myCustomService));
```

to have possibility to start/stop it as these 3 services.

Comment: It is my custom service, which works as tunnel service. In other words I am trying to embed something like server part of this client-server pair https://github.com/sailro/Bdtunnel .

Comment: What about if you write an interface and a service method that use your custom service? You can easily expose it as wcf and if will do the "bridge" between your wcf clients and your custom service.

Comment: oh, good idea. Thank you, will try this way. Write your answer and I will mark it